# CLARION DATABASES

Tags: database, migration, odbc, clarion, tps

I have a very old aplication made in Clarion. I need to access the data externally by using the ODBC driver. The problem is that the data is stored in .DAT and .K0 files. As far as I know the data needs to be store in .TPS files in order to use de ODBC driver. Is there any way to migrate the data to .TPS files instead of the .DAT files and have users continue working without noticing the change?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily copy/convert the data to another format for ODBC or other purposes, but without the source code to the Clarion application, you wont be able to switch the data format the program uses.